# Can't connect to Big SQL from Analytics for Apache Hadoop on IBM Bluemix

Tags: hadoop, db2, ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop, bigsql

I am using the newest version 'Analytics for Apache Hadoop' on IBM Bluemix.
I am following the tutorial to config the ODBC driver. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.analyze.doc/doc/bsql_odbc_windows.html

I have downloaded the 10.5 Data Server Driver package and configured the db2dsdriver.cfg.

```
<configuration>
  <dsncollection>
    <dsn alias="bigsql" name="bigsql" host="bi-hadoop-prod-2208.services.dal.bluemix.net" port="51000"/>
  </dsncollection>
<databases>
  <database name="bigsql" host="bi-hadoop-prod-2208.services.dal.bluemix.net" port="51000">
  </database>
</databases>
</configuration>
```

Here's my server info

```
"userid": "xxxxxx",
"password": "xxxxx",
"BigSqlUrl": "jdbc:db2://bi-hadoop-prod-2208.services.dal.bluemix.net:51000/bigsql;sslConnection=true",
```

When I try to use db2cli to verify the connection, I got:

```
[FAILED]: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/ IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected:"169.54.58.208".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10054", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001
```

Does anybody meet the same issue?

Comment: Here in the manual is a [list of possible reasons for the error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql30081n.html) - search for "10054".

Comment: If you are configuring an ODBC driver, why the JDBC URL? The error message tells you it cannot reach the DB2 instance at the specified address and port, so check if it is indeed listening on that port, that the instance is up, and that it is configured to use SSL.

Comment: You are right. It should not be a JDBC URL. From the document, I don't find any information about the ODBC address and port. The document is not following up with this new version (released on 07/23/2015)

Answer (score 0):

could you simply check that you are able to reach port 51000 on the server bi-hadoop-prod-2208.services.dal.bluemix.net?
You can for example run a telnet like this

telnet bi-hadoop-prod-2208.services.dal.bluemix.net 51000

The errors seems related to a connection error, like you aren't able to connect to the server to a firewall, a port blocked, and so on.